# ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden in string array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In my VB.net project, I am trying to call up multiple programs using an array to help clean up my code.

Currently, I have this code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartServer.Click
    Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo()
    Dim prochide As New ProcessStartInfo()
    prochide.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
                proc.WorkingDirectory = TextBox1.Text
                proc.FileName = "xserver.exe"
                Process.Start(proc)
                proc.FileName = "yserver.exe"
                Process.Start(proc)
                proc.FileName = "zserver.exe"
                Process.Start(proc)
            Else
                prochide.WorkingDirectory = TextBox1.Text
                prochide.FileName = "xserver.exe"
                Process.Start(prochide)
                prochide.FileName = "yserver.exe"
                Process.Start(prochide)
                prochide.FileName = "zserver.exe"
                Process.Start(prochide)
            End If
     End Sub
```

What this does is allows me to hide the windows so they show up in task manager but the windows don't actually show up.

However, I would prefer to switch with this code or something similar to clean it up:

```
Dim servers(0 To 2) As String
servers(0) = "xserver.exe"
servers(1) = "yserver.exe"
servers(2) = "zserver.exe"
```

Then I can simplify the code:

```
 Dim directory As String = TextBox1.Text
                For Each fileName As String In servers
                Next
```

However, I cannot figure out how to hide the windows in an array, since the .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden does not seem to work with array strings. Is there another way I can do this?Changing the method is fine, I just want to try to clean up the code since it seems a bit bulky right now.

Comment: I edited my answer. If you get an error on `Dim servers(3) As String = New String() {}` remove the `= New String() {}` part.

Comment: Back again with another edit. By the way are you using Option Strict? That may be the reason for the errors. We'll just have to find a way around it

Comment: I tried it, it seems some of the errors are no longer present, but now, when I go to launch the exe files, I get: Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array. This was after removing the = New String(). It failed using that.

Comment: Where do you get that error? On the `servers(0) = "xserver.exe|1"...` lines? May I ask if you're using option strict/explicit etc on/off?

Comment: Hey @jvanosda. I've written you a code that atleast works for me :). Please tell me if you get it to work!

Comment: It works now. Thank you for your help Vincent. But, can I ask how this flags the hidden window? Because right now, I cannot make the consoles visible. They are working as intended, but no option for checking my check state then creating a visible window.

Comment: Look at this: `xserver.exe|1` - The '1' in the end of the text is the index for the `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` property. To open a visible process, change the '1' to '0', like this: `xserver.exe|0`. Also, please mark my reply as the answer if it worked for you. There's a little check mark on the left of my answer which you can tick. :)

Comment: No problem, I was going to mark it anyways, just wanted to poke with it a little more. Thanks for your help. I guess my key is how do I tie the 1/0 in
Dim servers() As String = New String() {"cmd.exe|1", "cmd.exe|1", "cmd.exe|1"}
to a toggle? I thought it might be one of the FileOptions, like
prochide.WindowStyle = CType(FileOptions(1), ProcessWindowStyle) and just change this to 0. So an "If CK.Checked=True, then prochide.WindowStyle = CType(FileOptions(0), ProcessWindowStyle), else, prochide.WindowStyle = CType(FileOptions(1), ProcessWindowStyle)

Comment: `FileOptions(0)` is the name and location of the .exe... Well to make it toggable you cannot use this code since it's only a one-time-use code. To be able to show or hide the window you gotta use the `ShowWindow` function: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow

Comment: Example: `ShowWindow(hWnd, 1)` - Change '1' to '0' to hide it again. `hWnd` is the process main window handle. You can get it through `Process.GetProcessesByName("xserver")(0).MainWindowHandle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've finally checked this out, and this works for me:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim servers() As String = New String() {"cmd.exe|1", "cmd.exe|1", "cmd.exe|1"}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim directory As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim prochide As New ProcessStartInfo()
        prochide.WorkingDirectory = directory
        For Each fileName As String In servers
            Dim FileOptions() As String = Split(fileName, "|")
            prochide.FileName = FileOptions(0)
            prochide.WindowStyle = CType(FileOptions(1), ProcessWindowStyle)
            Process.Start(prochide)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

When using `New String()` you cannot declare the array with a limit. So that was our problem. :)

So instead of `Dim servers(3)...` or `Dim servers(0 To 2)...` you have to use `Dim servers()...`

Comment: This:

`Dim servers(3) As String = New String() {"xserver.exe|" & CStr(CInt(ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)), "yserver.exe|" & CStr(CInt(ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden)), "zserver.exe|" & CStr(CInt(ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden))}`
Gives this error: Explicit initialization is Not permitted for arrays declared with explicit bounds.

Comment: Bleh, same problem. It is still giving me the Explicit initialization error. Seems like this is the problem I have not been able to overcome to combine them all together so they are not repeated over and over again.

Comment: Even if you remove `= New String() {}`?

Comment: @jvanosda remove the implied `3` (which should actually be `2`)